# Month changes while convert NSString to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Here is my code:

```
NSString *date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"start_date"]];
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"start_time"]];  
NSString *dateAndTime = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",date,time];
```

Here My **date is : 2019-03-14** and my **time is : 18:40:00** and **dateAndTime is: 2019-03-14 18:40:00**

Now when I convert `NSString` to `NSDate` it gives different month.
Here is my buggy code :

```
// convert to date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    //dateFormat.dateFormat = @"dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss";
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate *dateTime = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateAndTime];
    NSLog(@"dateTime : %@",dateTime);
```

Now the o/p is **2019-01-14 13:10:00 +0000**
Here time and month both changed.

So What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The date format is wrong, just a typo:

- `mm` is minute
- `MM` is month

  ```
  [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
  ```